# Parsing Links and Receiving Extra Blanks

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, html-parsing, append

I am parsing a webpage for http links by first parsing out all the anchored tags, then parsing out the href tags, then running a regex to remove all tags that aren't independent links (like href="/img/link.php"). The following code works correctly, but also appends lots of blank lines in between the parsed links.

```
while (parse.ParseNext("a", out tag))
{
    string value;
    //A REGEX value, this one finds proper http address'
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$");
    if (tag.Attributes.TryGetValue("href", out value))
    {
        string value2;
        //Start finding matches...
        Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(value);
        value2 = matchResults.Value;
            lstPages.AppendText(value2 + "\r\n");                        
    }
}
```

To fix this, I added the following code and it works to clean up the list:

```
if (value2 != "")
{
    lstPages.AppendText(value2 + "\r\n");
}
```

However, I

1. Don't believe this is the most efficient way to go about this and
2. Still don't understand where the `!= ""` lines come from.

My actual question is on both of these but more for issue #2, as I would like to learn why I receive these results, but also if there is a more efficient method for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting an empty string in `value2` is that `matchResults.Value == ""` if the regular expression fails to match.  Instead of checking if `value2 != ""`, you could directly check `matchResults.Success` to see if the regular expression matched.  You're basically doing that, anyway, since your particular regular expression would never match an empty string, but checking `matchResults.Success` would be more straightforward.

Another thing to consider is that it's not necessary to create the Regex object every iteration of your loop.  Here are the modifications I suggest:

```
//A REGEX value, this one finds proper http address'
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$");
while (parse.ParseNext("a", out tag))
{
    string value;

    if (tag.Attributes.TryGetValue("href", out value))
    {
        string value2;
        //Start finding matches...
        Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(value);
        if (matchResult.Success)
        {
            value2 = matchResult.Value;
            lstPages.AppendText(value2 + "\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var html = new HtmlDocument();
    var request = WebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256982/parsing-links-and-recieving-extra-blanks/6257328#6257328") as HttpWebRequest;
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        html.Load(responseStream);
    }

    foreach (var absoluteHref in html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[starts-with(@href, 'http')]"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(absoluteHref.Attributes["href"].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you had read the question a little more carefully, you'd see that he isn't parsing the [X]HTML using regular expressions.  He's using the regular expression to check the value of the `href` attribute. -1

Comment: This isn't what I selected as an answer because it didn't fit what I was trying for in this particular project (I was trying not to have to rebuild it on the Agility pack :p). However, this answer is really awesome and will be noted for future use!

Answer (score -1):

`TryGetValue` is a generic Method (of `Type T`). If it doesnt have any value to return, it returnd the `default value of the type`, which is `String.Empty` or `""` for String

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why `matchResults.Value == ""` part of the time. -1